# Problem reading a numeric value from an excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My problem is that I have an excel in which one of the columns has a numeric format (which I cannot change) and when reading it from java it reads the entire value with commas. For example, if I fill a cell in that column with the value **3123456,89** in my excel, the excel shows it as **3.123.456,89** but java reads it and shows it to me as **3,123,456,89**.

When I try to pass the value of that cell to Double, I don't get the correct value. The way I read the cell value is as follows:

```
cell = row.getCell(cont);
stringValue = new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell);
```

Comment: Which library are you using the read Excel?

Comment: If you don't want the number formatted as defined in the Excel file, don't use `DataFormatter`, just use the `double` value directly: `cell.getNumericCellValue()`

Comment: @Andreas The problem is that it goes through all the cells of the excel and not only do I have numerical values, if I put that when it is a String value it will jump error

Comment: Do constructing the `DataFormatter` having a explicit `Locale`. Else it uses the default locale of your system which seems to be not correct as thousands separator and decimal separator both are comma. For example do: `DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.US);
stringValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);` That always leads to formatted strings in `en_US` format. Try other locales if needed.

Comment: *"if I put [getNumericCellValue()] when it is a String value it will jump error"* Then only call that method when it's a numeric value, as identified by the `cell.getCellType()` method.